# I can't download a file after render a Primefaces component

Tags: primefaces

I try to upload a file, process it and then download it. I can upload it and the internal process goes well but when I try to download it nothing happens.

My download button is rendered after doing click upload button. If I don't hide the download button, I be able to download the file without problems.

The problem is maybe in the rendered attribute.

**xhtml**

```
<p:fileUpload 
    fileUploadListener="#{portabilidadIPTV.upload}"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls?x)$/" 
    sizeLimit="100000" 
    description="Seleccione un archivo"
    invalidFileMessage="Tipo de archivo inválido" 
    fileLimit="1"
    messageTemplate="Seleccione un archivo válido"
    label="Elegir archivo"
    uploadLabel="Portar"
    cancelLabel="Cancelar"
    invalidSizeMessage="El tamaño de archivo debe ser menor a 90 KB"
    fileLimitMessage="Sólo puede cargar un archivo"
    update="resultados"/>               

<h:panelGroup id="resultados">
    <p:commandButton 
        value="Descargar" 
        ajax="false" 
        icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
        rendered="#{portabilidadIPTV.portabilidadRealizada}">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{portabilidadIPTV.archivoDescargado}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**managed bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="portabilidadIPTV")
public class PortabilidadIPTV implements Serializable{              

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UploadedFile archivo;
    private File archivoCargado;            
    private boolean portabilidadRealizada;

    @PostConstruct      
    public void init(){
        setPortabilidadRealizada(false);
    }

    // Download File
    public StreamedContent getArchivoDescargado() {

        File archivo = new File("examplePath"); //some path
        DefaultStreamedContent dsc = null;
        try {
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(archivo);
            dsc = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain","Portabilidad_Resultados.xlsx");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dsc;         
    }


    // Getters & Setters

    public boolean isPortabilidadRealizada() {
        return portabilidadRealizada;
    }

    public void setPortabilidadRealizada(boolean portabilidadRealizada) {
        this.portabilidadRealizada = portabilidadRealizada;
    }       

}
```

Comment: The `n` is missing: `redered`. Is it correct in your actual source?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.Yes, It is in my actual source.